# T-SQL: Concept similar to C# params

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Does T-SQL allow a variable number of arguments to a stored procedure like `params` in C#?

**EDIT**:  I'm using SQL Server 2005.  That 2008 answer makes me wish we were using it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not for things like UDFs or stored procedures.  That's what tables are for.  Put the values in a table somewhere (with a common key) and pass the correct key to your procedure.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL 2008 there's Table-Valued Parameters (TVPs)

Your stored proc can accept lists of parameters..

Finally we're able to do a IN clause without relying on XML!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Typically

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sptest 
( @xml TEXT )
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @flag1 INT
DECLARE @flag2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @flag3 DATETIME

DECLARE @idoc INT
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT @flag1 = firstparam, flag2 = secondparam, flag3 = thirdparam
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/root', 2) WITH
( firstparam INT, secondparam VARCHAR(50), thirdparam DATETIME) as x

END


exec sptest '<root><firstparam>5</firstparam><secondparam>Joes Bar</secondparam><thirdparam>12/30/2010</thirdparam></root>'
```

Extend as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I've seen to passing in params or arrays is to pass in an XML string, dump that to a temporary table/table variable and work with it from that point.  Not the easiest when you want to manually run a stored procedure, but it works as a work around to the lack of array/dynamic param support.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a little function to separate a CSV string into a table

That way I could go

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM myTable
WHERE myTable.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.SplitIDs('1,2,3,4,5...'))
```

My function is below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIDs]
(
    @IDList varchar(500)
)
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table
(
    ID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID varchar(10), @Pos int

    SET @IDList = LTRIM(RTRIM(@IDList))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @IDList, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@IDList, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @ID = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@IDList, @Pos - 1)))
            IF @ID <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @ParsedList (ID) 
                VALUES (CAST(@ID AS int)) --Use Appropriate conversion
            END
            SET @IDList = RIGHT(@IDList, LEN(@IDList) - @Pos)
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @IDList, 1)

        END
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

I'm sure there are better ways to implement this, this is one way I found online and it works well for what I'm doing. If there are some improvement that can be made please comment.